# Power BI - Calculate networking days without calendar table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Is there a way to calculate networking days without using the calendar table.

My Starting date goes to 1/1/1901 and ending date comes to 1/11/2010.

So, I don't really want to  build a calendar table that is that much bigger.

Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to edit query right click on the left pane `New Query > Blank Query` and use this code to create a function. Lets call it `WorkdayDiff`:

```
= (StartDate as date, EndDate as date) as number =>

let
    DateList = List.Dates(StartDate, Number.From(EndDate - StartDate) , #duration(1, 0, 0, 0)),
    RemoveWeekends = List.Select(DateList, each Date.DayOfWeek(_, Day.Monday) < 5),
    CountDays = List.Count(RemoveWeekends)
in
    CountDays
```

Now you can use the function with

```
= WorkdayDiff([StartDateColumn], [EndDateColumn])
```